# Facebook API without client authentication for public content

Tags: php, api, authentication, facebook

I'm developing a site for a client who already have the photos of his products on Facebook, and he wants the same albums to be replicated over his site. I was already using Facebook Connect, so I dropped a combination of `photos.getAlbums` and `photos.get` to dynamically make the galleries.

So far so good, but then I realized that if there's no user logged trough FBC, no session is created and the API becomes unusable, even for content that is publicly available. I obviously want to show the albums to everyone and not just the people who connect their accounts.

Is this how all functions in the Facebook API work? What's the best (easier to implement) workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of September 2010, you can now authenticate just as an application, with no associated user. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for details. Or you can run this example code to get an access token:

```
curl -F grant_type=client_credentials \
 -F client_id=your_app_id \
 -F client_secret=your_app_secret \
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that link now redirects to a fairly useless page about Facebook Login. It seems that in their promotion of Login, they're making it even less clear that this "app token" method is even an option. However, it's still shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token), which is reassuring.

Comment: @nkorth thank you so much for that, couldn't find it no matter how I googled or scoured the docs

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I managed to solve this situation by developing a small backend that requires the client to login to Facebook once and give `offline_access` [extended permission](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions) to the FB app, so I can save his session key and use it to authenticate the Facebook API client every time I need to use FQL to get non-public content.

One could obviously add some caching in the middle to avoid unnecessary requests to Facebook, but it's been working fine for months now without hitting any limits that I know of.

Comment: Great answer- this seems like the most up to date way to do this. Out of curiousity - how did you authenticate the user? I'm currently using the JS SDK on the front end, however for my App (CMS) I want to publish posts to a facebook page when an editor publishes a post to their website. (Then store PostId for likes/comments/etc) Ideally, I would store the username/pw for a fb page admin and use graph api to auth invisibly. Any examples of this? Thanks!

Comment: As lacker says, the FB auth scheme changed. Follow the link and example in his answer to understand it. I'm marking that one as the correct.

Comment: Here is an updated link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-extended.

However, the offline_access permission has been deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense to me - I have a (relatively simple) app that renders in facebook even if the user has never logged into facebook before (in which case it displays demo data).

When using the facebook PHP library, I just do this:

$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret);

No session id required - but, obviously, api functions that depend on information about the user aren't going to work.

You can also look into an ["infinite session"](http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=18) for your app - you could create an infinite session key for yourself and use that session to access the API.

Comment: Thanks, I can obviously render my app (in this case is just backend code) without a user session, but I can't use any of the API functions that would let me pull content from the albums.
The "infinite session" idea sounded good, but it's partially deprecated: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/New_Design_Platform_Changes#Changes_to_Session_Keys