# Getting facebook wall posts without user login on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, request, nsdata, token

Edit: I found the solution here: 
[Using app access token in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244693/using-app-access-token-in-ios)

Hi,

I read in this thread:
[Facebook API without client authentication for public content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000773/facebook-api-without-client-authentication-for-public-content)
that it is possible to make facebook api graph requests without the need to log in as a user.
I tried getting the app access token with a NSURLConnection request,
but from there I don't know what to do.

How do I get the NSData response into the right format for the token (which is what, a NSString?)?

And how do I send a facebook graph request with the aquired token?

Or is there a simpler way to receive public posts from a facebook wall without the need to login as a user?

Greetings
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Hey i'm struggling a litle bit with the same problem.

Since a couple of days Facebook changed some things concerning having an access tokken. Now, if you only want to read a users posts you will need to have an access token (even if this info is public).

Luckily you can also use the app access token. I'm trying to figure out how to fix this, but here is some information about that: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ (chech app login)

Comment: I already read that and the app login is actually what I am trying to do, but I just don't know how to process the token-response of the server after I requested the token. I need the token as a NSString to attach to the graph api call. But I get a NSData Object, how can I get the token string out of that?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured that part out: 'code'([[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) seems to give me a valid token string. But I still don't know how to send the proper graph request. I tried requestWithGraphPath:@"xyz/posts?" and the token string attached but that gives me an invalid URL error.