# Using app access token in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

Since Facebook changed their policy on having a access token or not I am now forced to include an access token to fetch a user public posts.

As read in the documentation I can use an app access token so I still can fetch the posts without asking a user for permissions. But since I have no clue how this works, and the facebook documentation doesn't give a example concerning how to implement this on IOS, I want to ask your help!

Does anyone has an example on how I need to implement this in my code? Thnx in advance!!

Comment: I made some progress, but still not there. I've managed to get the app access token from facebook. But what do I have to do with this? If I use it in the reqestWithGrapPath link it gives a bad URL error(Probably due this "|" sign in the access token)

Comment: no one? I'm not getting how to use the access_token I get back...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for, but if you are trying to do something simple like getting the public posts of a user, you can do it like this.

Use the following request to get the token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I'm guessing you've got your app id and secret since you've retrieved the token already. Anyway, the token will be returned in the response like this:

```
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Parse out the token: and put it in the following request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/posts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You can use the following code to parse out the token:

```
    NSRange access_token_range = [responseString rangeOfString:@"access_token="];
    if (access_token_range.length > 0) {
        int from_index = access_token_range.location + access_token_range.length;
        NSString *access_token = [responseString substringFromIndex:from_index];

        NSLog(@"access_token:  %@", access_token);
    }
```

EDIT: The get posts URL will give BadURL due to illegal chars. You can do like this to fix it:

```
NSString *encodedURLString = [yourUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString];
```

I'm not using the Facebook SDK, so I don't really know how it works, but I guess that you should do something like this:

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[user_id]/feed" 
                  andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:ACCESS_TOKEN forKey:@"access_token"]
              andHttpMethod:@"GET"
                andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I'm using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) to do my GET requests, it's quite simple to use

Comment: Hello Joel, thnx for your reply. At the moment I can retrieve the access_token. If I log this token it looks like this: access_token=197111333955378|v2oG97DcTZZCCo4hAX_0y6_q97w . So that's ok, isn't it? But what do I do next with this token? I use the following line to get the data I want [facebook requestWithGraphPath:192380620220564/posts andParams:params andDelegate:self];. If I combine the the requestWithGraphPath link with the acces token. I will get an error of a badURL (Probably due to the "|" sign in the acces_token)

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer with a bit of code. I got the badUrl error as well, so I fixed it like that. And since I'm not using the Facebook SDK, I'm not really sure how you should use the token. But I think you should put it in "andParams"

Comment: Thanks, it's actually loading didLoad method! Only problem now is that the result is almost empty. If I log the result from the request I only get the following: result (
    "https://graph.facebook.com/192080534327564/posts"
) and the parser makes the app stop because their is no/not enough content in de result

Comment: You can try to enter the entire url in a browser window (in Safari at least), and see what is returned. https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/posts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: I've tried that. It gives me the following error:    "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#15) Requires session when calling from a desktop app"

Comment: Hm.. I don't know why you get that error.. How did you request the access token? Was it with grant_type=client_credentials? How did you get you app id and secret?

Comment: Yep, did it like this: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1423423655378&client_secret=e244e2qq334234b87ea1082e2c033f0bb193f983&grant_type=client_credentials"]; (changed the id's off course)

Comment: Weird, it works just fine for me. But try to do everything manually first to make sure that everything works like it should. First, put the following url in your browser window https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials It will return the token. Copy and paste the token into the following url and put it in your browser window https://graph.facebook.com/10465958627/posts?access_token=THE_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Ok, just tried it. But sadly still gives the same error (Requires session...). Thnx for the big effort so far!!!

Comment: Hm. sorry :( I don't think I can help you in that case, since that exact scenario works for me. The only other thing I can think of is if it's possible to create different types of facebook apps (mobile, desktop, etc), and that your App Id belongs to a desktop app, and can't be used "without a session".. But thats just me guessing

Comment: If you go to http://developers.facebook.com/ and "My Apps". Click your app and then "edit settings". Under the section "Mobile and Devices", do you have "HTML5 / mobile web" or "Native app" selected?

Comment: It says "native app". Probably shouldn't, if I change it to HTML it load the good way in safari. Unfortunately still not ok in ios, but I'm going to try some things. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: Finally!! It worked!!! Thank you sooo much! Last problem was due to the full link in requestWithGrapPath https://graph.facebook.com/. When I removed this it worked! Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this, the API documentation states

> App Login allows you to take various administrative actions for your app, such as retrieving Insights data or approving Requests. Graph API calls that require an app access token are clearly denoted in the API reference."

I think it might be a security risk since someone could intercept your app access token and do all these things via the API. Not to mention having client_secret (which is basically a password for your app) being embedded in the iOS app. I think app logins are more for the PHP servers to use.