# Get App access token with Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to get an Facebook App access token to get the Facebook page feed. If I send a request like this: `[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials"]` I get a valid access token but I can't use this one in the FBSession because the accessToken property is read-only. 
So the question is: how do I obtain an Facebook App access token with FBSession?

Comment: You can refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244693/using-app-access-token-in-ios for right answer

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully login then you can get accesstoken using

```
[[FBSession activeSession] accessToken];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Scrumptious sample, along with the other stuff Facebook has provided.

I did mine like:

`[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];`

Comment: Question is about app access token, not about user access token.