# Does facebook expose an api call that does not requre authentication to read public feeds?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want a simple mobile app to be able to read a public facebook feed. I do not want to challenge the user for a username and password. Is this possible without writing/communicating with a 3rd party service?

I found this:
[Facebook API without client authentication for public content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000773/facebook-api-without-client-authentication-for-public-content)
But it looks like things have changed slightly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that I'm a bit confuse about your question, however to read a public facebook content like the public info of a page you have just to do something like: http://graph.facebook.com/19292868552/
With NO access token required.
But if you want to read a public feed of a page or something then you actually need the access token ( http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552%2Ffeed ).

So, how to read stream without authentication from client-side? Well, the 1st thing I can think is to get only one access token with offline_access permission and use only this token for each client (ugly but it works) this kind of token never expires, anyway the offline access permission is [being deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/), so I'm a bit stuck in here, you can, anyway, handle the token (extending expiration or request another one) from your custom server (if you have one), or if you are using native SDK, Android for instance, I think you can use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#extend_token)